# How to perform .describe() method on variables that have boolean data type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the summary statistics of the columns of a data frame with data type: Boolean.

When I run:`df.describe()` it only gives me the summary statistics for numerical (in this case float) data types. When I change it to `df.describe(include=['O'])`, it gives me only the object data type.

In either case, the summary statistics for Boolean data types are not provided.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of summary statistics do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want but you can do so with a `include="all"` argument.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True, 1], [False, 2]])
df.describe(include="all")

        0   1
count   2   2.000000
unique  2   NaN
top     True    NaN
freq    1   NaN
mean    NaN     1.500000
std     NaN     0.707107
min     NaN     1.000000
25%     NaN     1.250000
50%     NaN     1.500000
75%     NaN     1.750000
max     NaN     2.000000

df.describe(include=[bool])  # will also work

        0
count   2
unique  2
top     True
freq    1
```

Reference

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be useful if you use `df.dtypes` to find out **data types of all columns**.And use `df.describe(include='data_type',exclude='data_type')` for **more specific** results.

```
ufo.dtypes
City                       object
Colors Reported            object
Shape Reported             object
State                      object
Time               datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
ufo.describe(exclude='datetime')



           City   Colors  Reported  Shape Reported  State
count     18216   2882              15597          18241
unique    6476    27                27             52
top       Seattle RED               LIGHT          CA
freq      187     780               2803           2529
```

here I simply excluded unwanted data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

df.describe(include=['object','bool']).T

## the T here is used for the transpose purpose